# Limitations on pointers to various types within a class family?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, derived-class

Suppose I have 4 classes: A,B,C, and D.

A is the base class.
B is derived from A.
C is derived from A.

D is derived from B.

I have vectors of each type of object.

I create a 5th class that is excluded from the related classes (family?), called Z.
Z contains a variable that points to an object of class A, called **purple.**

Can I create an "inter-family" universal pointer by doing something like:
    A * pUniversal;

And point pUniversal to A,B,C, or D interchangeably to an object stored in the vector of its type.. Then set the **purple** variable of Z to be pUniversal?

Comment: you should tag your question according to the language you are using , and even write some code to support your question.

Comment: Really?.. it's a universal question

Comment: `A * pUniversal` doesnt feel universal to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It's one of the main benefits of having derived classes.

If you have functions in `A` that should be implemented by `B` or `C`, make sure they're virtual.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the confirmation! Yup, I love using virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! No I am not Obama =P but you might consider reading something about [`reinterpret_cast<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword (operator).

---

**EDIT:**`reinterpret_cast<>` could be used to cast pointers of base class to pointers of derived class.

Comment: Although `reinterpret_cast` _can_ be used for downcasting, it is not the appropriate tool. Moreover, the question isn't about downcasting anyway.

Comment: static_cast<> would be better, but with a little forethought you shouldn't even need that.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector> 
  class A
  {
  public:
    virtual void SayHi() {
      std::cout<<"A says hi"<< std::endl;
    }

  };

    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        virtual void SayHi() {
          std::cout<<"B says hi"<<std::endl;
        }

    };

    class C: public A 
    {
    public:
        virtual void SayHi() {
          std::cout<<"C says hi"<<std::endl;
        }
    };

    typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
    typedef std::vector<APtr> Container;

  int main()
  {
      Container myContainer;
      // Store A's instance or any of its derivatives.
      myContainer.push_back(APtr(new A));
      myContainer.push_back(APtr(new B));
      myContainer.push_back(APtr(new C));

      for(/*Container::iterator or */ auto pbase = myContainer.begin(); pbase != myContainer.end(); pbase++)
          (*pbase)->SayHi();

      myContainer.clear();

      return 0;
  }
```